# Asynchronous file uploading working (in fact not working) differently in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, forms, image, xmlhttprequest

I am testing line by line resizing and uploading files within a form client-side.
There is a button to select a file, javascript throws an alert about image attributes, resizes the image, assigns it to a hidden field and posts the form. I started with a single image and the relevant code is:

```
HTML

    <form action="add2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addform">

<input  type="file" id="i1_file" onchange="resize('i1_file', 'addform')"  />
<input type="hidden" name="uploadfile" id="image1" value="" />

Javascript

 function resize(inputid,  formid)
{
     var inpFiles = document.getElementById(inputid);
    var file = inpFiles.files[0];
... Initial file checks here: type, size etc...

                           var dataurl = null;
                           // create <img> element
                           var img = document.createElement("img");
                           var reader = new FileReader(); 
                           var image = document.getElementById('image1');
                          // document.write("Before image1 :"  + image.name + "<br />");
                           reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                            img.src = e.target.result;
                            img.onload = function() {
                           // Once you have the image preview in an <img> element, you can draw this image in a <canvas> element to pre-process the file.

                            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                            var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
                            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                                  var width = img.width;
                                  var height = img.height;
                                  //document.write("src " + img.src + "<br />");
                                  document.write("width " + img.width + "<br />");
                                  document.write("height " + img.height + "<br />");
                                  if ((width > 1024) && (width > height)) 
                                  {
                                    var new_width = 1024;
                                    var ratio = new_width / width;
                                    var new_height = Math.round(height * ratio);
                                    }  
                                    else if (height > 768)
                                     {
                                        var new_height = 768;
                                        var ratio = new_height / height;
                                        var new_width = Math.round(width * ratio);
                                     }
                                    else
                                    {
                                       var new_width = width;
                                       var new_height = height;
                                    }
                                    document.write("new_height: " + new_height + "<br />");
                                    canvas.width = new_width;
                                    canvas.height = new_height;
                                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
                                    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,new_width, new_height);
                                    // save canvas as dataUrl
                                    dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.8);
                                    document.write("FormData " + formid + "<br />"); 
                                    //document.write("dataurl: " + dataurl + "<br />");

                                    image.value = dataurl;
                                    //var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById(formid));
                                    document.write("Before FormData "  + "<br />");
                                    var fd = new FormData(document.forms["addform"]); 

                                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                    document.write("Posting <br />" + xhr.readyState );
                                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                       // OK
                       alert('response:'+xhr.responseText);
                       // here you can use the result (xhr.responseText)
            } else {
                       // not OK
                       alert('failure!');
            }
        }
};
                                    xhr.open('POST', 'add2.php', true);
                                    document.write("After Open <br />"  + xhr.readyState);

                                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
                                    document.write("Before Send <br />" );
                                    xhr.send(fd);
                                    console.log(xhr.response);
                              } //onload
                           }   

                                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                       }
```

The first browser was Firefox and it hangs after producing this output (i.e. up to xhr.open):
width 4176
height 3120
new_height: 765
FormData addform
Before FormData
Posting
0

Chrome did not redirect at all and stayed on the same page where the form was.

IE10 only output "width 4176" (the very first debugging print).

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong and why the behaviour is so different in modern browsers?

Comment: Have you checked client side logs? (using developer tools in the browsers)

Comment: You are calling `document.write` after the document is loaded. I guess you want to use `console.log` instead.

Comment: @Roland Starke Thanks for pointing out that console.log needs to be used. This confirmed that the form was indeed posted. Now I can move forward to testing redirection to the target page and processing multiple images. BTW, client side logs did not show any helpful info.